# Creating Markers for svg chart using d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, markers

[My Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/V6Qr8/64/)

I'm using the following code to create markers based on this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292). How can I make the children nodes point to the parent instead of the parent pointing to the children?

```
vis.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
.data(force.links())
.enter().append("marker")
.attr("id", function(d) { console.log(d); return d.source.id; })
.attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
.attr("refX", 7)
.attr("refY", -1)
.attr("markerWidth", 6)
.attr("markerHeight", 6)
.attr("orient", "auto")
.append("path")
.attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");
```

It seems that it isn't correct to bind the `force.link` data to the markers. I find there are duplicated ids and markers in the example:

```
<defs>
      <marker id="53" viewBox="0 -5 10 10" refX="7" refY="-1" markerWidth="6" markerHeight="6" orient="auto"><path d="M0,-5L10,0L0,5"></path></marker>
      <marker id="53" viewBox="0 -5 10 10" refX="7" refY="-1" markerWidth="6" markerHeight="6" orient="auto"><path d="M0,-5L10,0L0,5"></path></marker>
      <marker id="53" viewBox="0 -5 10 10" refX="7" refY="-1" markerWidth="6" markerHeight="6" orient="auto"><path d="M0,-5L10,0L0,5"></path></marker>
       ....................
```

Full code:

```
var w = 960,
    h = 500,
    node,
    path,
    root, nodes, links;

var force, vis;
var LoadData = true;

function update() {
    if (force) force.stop();
    nodes = flatten(root);
    links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

    force.nodes(nodes)
        .links(links)
        .linkDistance(120)
        .charge(-500)
        .start();

    vis.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(force.links())
    .enter().append("marker")
    .attr("id", function(d) { console.log(d); return d.source.id; })
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 7)
    .attr("refY", -1)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

    path = vis.selectAll("path.link");
    path = path.data(force.links());
    path.exit().remove();
    path.enter().append("svg:path")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("marker-end",function(d){ 
          return "url(#"+ d.source.id + ")";
        });
    vis.selectAll(".node .simpleDiv").remove();

    node = vis.selectAll(".node");
    node = node.data(force.nodes());
    node.exit().remove();
    node.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .on("click", click)
        .call(force.drag);

    node.append("foreignObject")
        .attr("class", "simpleDiv")
        .attr("width", function (d) {
        var f = document.createElement("span");
        f.id = "hiddenText";
        f.style.display = 'hidden';
        f.style.padding = '0px';
        f.innerHTML = d.name;
        document.body.appendChild(f);
        textWidth = f.offsetWidth;
        var f1 = document.getElementById('hiddenText');
        f1.parentNode.removeChild(f1);
        return textWidth + 50;
    })
        .attr("overflow", "visible")
        .attr("height", 40)
        .append("xhtml:div").attr("class", "mainDiv").style("cursor", hoverStyle)
        .html(function (d) {
        var htmlString = "";
            htmlString += "<div class='userImage' style='border-color:" + color(d) + "'><img src='' width='30' height='30'></div>";
            htmlString += "<div class='content' style='color:" + color(d) + ";'>" + d.name + "</div>";
            htmlString += "<div style='clear:both;'></div>";
        return htmlString;
    });
}

function tick() {
    path.attr("d", function (d) {

        var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
            dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
            dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
    });

    node.attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + (d.x - 15) + "," + (d.y - 15) + ")";
    });

}

function color(d) {
    return d._children ? "#3182bd" : d.children ? "#2044D2" : "#fd8d3c";
}

function hoverStyle(d) {
    return d._children ? "pointer" : d.children ? "pointer" : "default";
}
// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
    }
    update();
}

var findNode = function (node) {
    for (var i in force.nodes()) {
        if (force.nodes()[i] === node) return true
    };
    return false;
}

    function flatten(root) {
        var nodes = [],
            i = 0;

        function recurse(node) {
            if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
            if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
            nodes.push(node);
        }

        recurse(root);
        return nodes;
    }

    function loadImage() {
       if (LoadData) {
            root = 
{ "brand":"32","id":"53","name":"AAA","parent_id":"0","children":
    [
        {"brand":"16","id":"536","name":"BBB","parent_id":"53"},         
        {"brand":"16","id":"547","name":"CCC","parent_id":"53"},
        {"brand":"16","id":"537","name":"EEE","parent_id":"53"},
        {"brand":"16","id":"538","name":"WWW","parent_id":"53"},
        {"brand":"14","id":"213","name":"KKK","parent_id":"53"},
        {"brand":"16","id":"540","name":"BBB","parent_id":"53"}
    ]
};
          force = d3.layout.force()
                .on("tick", tick)
                .size([w, h]);
          vis = d3.select("#chart").append("svg:svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h);
            update();
            LoadData = false;
         }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `marker-end` to `marker-start`.  This will place the marker at the start of the path which in your case will make the lines point from the children to the parent.  You'll need to mess with your path function a little since moving the arrowheads currently places them all on top of one another inside the parent circle.

Comment: Thank you. Is there anything wrong with the duplicated ids for the markers? I find there are a lot of markers with the same id `53` which is the  parent's id.

Comment: You should only define the marker once, not one per path.  You can set the marker id to `#marker` or something and then use it `url(#marker)` for all of your paths.  You only need different definitions if you need them to look different (`auto` for orientation will rotate them correctly for you, do you don't need to worry about that).